# How to calculate Percentage by group of columns

Tags: sqlite

I could not able to write a query to calculate percentage by grouping columns.

```
Itemname,value
A,3
B,2
A,7
B,8
```

Output should be

```
itemname,value,percentage
A,3,30
A,7,70
B,2,20
B,8,80
```

Percentage  is  calculated with the group by itemname (ex A).

Comment: Code markup is done with four spaces. Don't use HTML markup, it's ugly.

Comment: I don't understand your question. How shall the percentage be calculated from the data? What is 100%?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_tab (
  Itemname VARCHAR(1),
  value INT
);

INSERT INTO my_tab VALUES ('A', 3);
INSERT INTO my_tab VALUES ('B', 2);
INSERT INTO my_tab VALUES ('A', 7);
INSERT INTO my_tab VALUES ('B', 8);

SELECT
    mt.itemname,
    mt.value,
    mt.value * 100 / agg.value_sum AS percentage
FROM
    my_tab mt
      JOIN (SELECT
                itemname,
                SUM(value) AS value_sum
              FROM my_tab
            GROUP BY itemname
      ) agg ON (mt.itemname = agg.itemname)
;
```

Check at SQLFiddle: <kbd>[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2c54f/4)</kbd>

Output:

```
Itemname    value    percentage
A               3            30
A               7            70
B               2            20
B               8            80
```